# How to verify correctness of login/password JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm creating very simple ATM machine. I have MySQL DB with columns like: loginID, password, money. I would like to change my method which can verify correctness of login and password at the beginning (and after this do something). So If login and password are correct, then I want to receive a message "Login successful" or Login unsuccessful". Right now I always have message "Login successful". How can I change it?

```
    public static void post () throws Exception{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("please enter user id:");
    String userId = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("please enter password:");
    String pass = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("how much you want to put");
    int money = sc.nextInt();

    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
        String sql = "UPDATE `BankDB`.`Info` SET `Money`= ? WHERE `ClientID`= ? AND `ClientPass` = ?";

        PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        posted.setInt(1, money);
        posted.setString(2, userId);
        posted.setString(3, pass);


        posted.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        System.out.println("Login was succesful");
    }
}
```

Comment: The finally clause will always be executed, whether or not an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding of the question is valid, you need to check that update command really updated something in DB.
In this case you need to get result from `posted.executeUpdate()`. If it is greater than zero, update updated record in DB and user name / password were correct.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` queries work even if their `WHERE` clauses choose zero rows. So your query

```
 UPDATE `BankDB`.`Info` SET `Money`= ? WHERE `ClientID`= ? AND `ClientPass` = ?
```

doesn't do anything if either part of the `WHERE` clause matches nothing.  But it still succeeds.

Generally you want to do something like shown in this outline.

1. `SELECT id, password FROM Info WHERE ClientId = ?`
2. Check the password for a match with the one provided by your web user. If it doesn't match, reject the transaction.
3. `UPDATE Info SET Money = Money + ?  WHERE id = ?` giving the `id` value you retrieved in the first step.

**DANGER** your way of validating the user's password is **incredibly dangerous** in a world infested with cybercriminals.  Storing plain-text passwords in a dbms is notorious for being the worst thing you can do about security. This is about password hashing in php, but its advice is valid for any language. Please read it.  http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php  Don't reinvent the flat tire in the area of password security. Please.